# How to tap-to-focus with react-native-camera

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, camera, react-native

I would like to let the user focus to take picture. But I don't know how it works.

I found on the documentation the section related to the problem : [react-native-camera](https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera#onfocuschanged) But is there any example to view how it works ? I don't any idea to implement this.

Furthermore, the [default option](https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera#defaultonfocuscomponent) didn't seem to work. I didn't have any visual feedback when I pressure camera's screen and it didn't seems to focus.

Someone can help me on this point ?

**Update : Solution**

It appears a bug was fix since long time, but at this time, the dependencie isn't up-to-date, so the feature didn't work. As a workaround before a new release `> 0.38.0`, add this link `https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera.git#8f37727be69132cdbfed95255c8bd010a1db5c7d` (with the hash of the last commit on master) to your `package.json`.

After this, add to the `<camera />` component `defaultOnFocusComponent={ true } onFocusChanged={ this.state.handleFocusChanged }` and `handleFocusChanged: () => {},` as an initial state

Comment: I haven't had experience with that component, but based on a quick reading of the docs, have you tried setting `defaultOnFocusComponent={true}` and `onFocusChanged` to any function, even a no-op. The docs are a bit ambigious, but they could be interpreted as saying that the tap-to-focus is disabled if these properties are not defined.

Comment: Or alternatively, have you tried defining `defaultOnFocusComponent={true}` and **not** defining a `onFocusChanged` handler, as the other way I can think the docs can be read is that they are mutually exclusive - one for default behavior, one for custom. Again, just guessing here :)

Comment: A third guess - are you using the latest release of the component, `v0.3.7`. It appears the tap-to-focus support was only added in `0.3.6`, so if you have a version older than that, those properties will not work. But now I will really stop guessing and let you weigh in :)

Comment: I tried everything, and nothing work. I am in `0.3.8` according to the npm dependencie version but the release is not available on github. I will open an issue on the github repository. Thanks anyway.